# How to make non-linear movements with a Follow Path constraint?

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, constraints

I try to achieve a non linear movement with the Follow Path constraint.

I linked my object to a bezier circle using the *Follow Path* constraint.
It follows the circle with a linear movement, meaning the speed of the object always stays the same.

I want to make the object move faster by time, by changing the curve of the evaluation time from linear to exponentially.

In short I want the movement of the object to get faster and faster. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Hi and welcome st22zy! If you are not already familiar with this site, please take the tour to learn how this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *Evaluation Time* property is keyframable, you can shape its F-curve to any function you like.

Select your bezier curve object, in the graph editor and expand it to show the *Evaluation Time* curve (add a keyframe if necessary if it doesn't show by default).

Under the *Modifier* panel add a *Generator* modifier, change poly order to $2$, and adjust the function to get the desired speed.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A possible way is to animate the *"offset"* of the constraint from 0 to some negative value:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can probably also add a generator to the offset property and make it exponential as well